# How do i 'sign' or 'name' row results? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the top 3 results and make each row specific.
For example,

The one with the most votes is number one,
The one with the second most votes is number two,
The one with the third most votes is number three,

Then I'd like to style them, and I have no idea where to start.

Is there a way to treat each row specially in a sence of 'order by row, if row is higher then second highest then *' ?

This is my current code:

```
                $filter = $_GET["filter"];
            if ($filter == "")  {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE Serverversion > 0 ORDER BY Votes DESC";
            } else if ($filter == "custom") {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE Servertype = 'custom' AND Serverversion > 0  ORDER BY Votes DESC";
            }  else if ($filter == "pvp")   {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE Servertype = 'pvp' AND Serverversion > 0  ORDER BY Votes DESC";
            }  else if ($filter == "economy")   {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE Servertype = 'economy' AND Serverversion > 0  ORDER BY Votes DESC";
            }  else if ($filter == "remake")    {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE Servertype = 'economy' AND Serverversion > 0 ORDER BY Votes DESC";
            }  else if ($filter == "all")   {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM toplist WHERE Serverversion > 0 ORDER BY Votes DESC";
            }

            if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
                while ($toplist = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="'.$toplist["Bannerlink"].'" width="468" height="60" /></td>
                        <td>'.ucfirst($toplist["Servername"]).'</td>
                        <td>'.ucfirst($toplist["Servertype"]).' (Rev. '.ucfirst($toplist["Serverversion"]).')</td>
                        <td>'.$toplist["Votes"].'</td>
                        <td><a href="'.$toplist["Serverwebsite"].'" target="blank" class="btn btn-primary">Visit Website</a></td>
                        <td><a href="profile.php?profile='.$toplist["ID"].'" class="btn btn-success">Visit profile</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
                $result->free();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a counter that increments in the loop. Then set a class based on the current row's position.

```
$n = 1;
while ($toplist = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $n = the row number, with the 1st row having the most votes.
    switch($n) {
        case 1:
            $class = '...';
            break;
        case 2:
           $class = '...';
           break;
        // and so on ...
        default:
           $class = '...';
    }
    echo "<tr class=\"$class\"> ...";
    $n++;
}
```